# What results about the topology of manifolds depend on the dimension mod 3?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

There are a lot of interesting results about the topology of manifolds that depend on the dimension of the manifold mod 2, mod 4, or mod 8.   The simplest ones involve the [cup product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_product)

$$ \smile \colon H^{n/2}(M,R) \times H^{n/2}(M,R) \to H^{n}(M,R) \cong R$$

where $n$, the dimension of $M$, is *even*, $R$ is a commutative ring, and the last isomorphism is present if $M$ is compact and oriented (or more generally $R$-oriented).

When $n$ is a multiple of $4$, this trick gives a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form

$$ \smile \colon H^{n/2}(M,\mathbb{R}) \times H^{n/2}(M,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$$

and the signature of this bilinear form is an important invariant called the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(topology)) of $M$.  In this case we also get a lattice $L$ that's the image of $H^{n/2}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ in $H^{n/2}(M,\mathbb{R})$, and a [unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form#unimodular) symmetric bilinear form

$$ \smile \colon L \times L \to \mathbb{Z}$$

which gives more refined information about $M$.  This is very important in the classification of compact oriented 4-dimensional manifolds.

When the dimension of $M$ equals 2 mod 4, we instead get a nondegenerate *skew-symmetric* bilinear form

$$ \smile \colon H^{n/2}(M,\mathbb{R}) \times H^{n/2}(M,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$$

otherwise known as a symplectic structure, and a unimodular skew-symmetric bilinear form

$$ \smile \colon L \times L \to \mathbb{Z}.$$

These data are not directly helpful in classifying manifolds because they're determined up to isomorphism by the dimension of $H^{n/2}(M,\mathbb{R})$, unlike in the case where $n$ is a multiple of $4$.  But if $M$ is equipped a 'framing', then we can get an interesting invariant by taking $R = \mathbb{Z}/2$ and improving the bilinear form above to a quadratic form.  This is called the [Kervaire invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kervaire_invariant).

There are subtler tricks involving spinors that depend heavily on the dimension of the manifold mod 8.  There's also a nice result that depends on the dimension of the manifold mod $2^n$ for all $n$: namely, any smooth compact $n$-dimensional manifold admits an immersion into Euclidean space of dimension $2n-H(n)$, where $H(n)$ is the number of 1's in the binary expansion of $n$.  (See Cohen's paper [The immersion conjecture for differentiable manifolds](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971304).)

All this made me wonder if there are interesting results about manifolds that depend on their dimension mod 3 — or for that matter, any number that's not just a power of 2.  Do you know any?

If $M$ is oriented and its dimension is a multiple of 3, we can use the cup product to get a trilinear form

$$ \smile \colon H^{n/3}(M,\mathbb{R}) \times H^{n/3}(M,\mathbb{R}) \times H^{n/3}(M,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$$

and if $L$ is the image of $H^{n/3}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ in $H^{n/3}(M,\mathbb{R})$ this restricts to give a trilinear form

$$ \smile \colon H^{n/3}(M,\mathbb{Z}) \times H^{n/3}(M,\mathbb{Z}) \times H^{n/3}(M,\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{Z}.$$

These are symmetric when $n$ is a multiple of 6 but skew-symmetric when $n$ equals 3 mod 6.

Of course this already is a partial answer to my question, and we could easily generalize to numbers other than 3.  But do these trilinear forms give nontrivial invariants of $M$?   Are they used for anything interesting?

In a quick attempt to search for this I bumped into a paper on cubic forms that are invariants of 12-dimensional manifolds:

- Fei Han, Ruizhi Huang, Kefeng Liu, Weiping Zhang, [Cubic forms, anomaly cancellation and modularity](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.02344).

Also, Ahmet Beyaz has a paper [A new construction of 6-manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.1085) that builds on a paper ([Classification problems in differential topology. V. On certain 6-manifolds](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01389738)) where C.T.C. Wall classified simply-connected, compact oriented 6-manifolds with spin structure and torsion-free cohomology with the help of the trilinear form

$$ \smile \colon H^{2}(M,\mathbb{Z}) \times H^{2}(M,\mathbb{Z}) \times H^{2}(M,\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{Z}.$$

But I don't know if either of these is part of a bigger story that involves the manifold's dimension mod 3, or 6, or 12.

Comment: For the special case of dimension 6, you might have a look at *Cubic forms and complex $3$-folds* by Okonek and Van de Ven, 
Enseign. Math. (2) 41 (1995), no. 3-4, 297–333. As the title indicates they are particularly interested in complex threefolds, but they have some more general remarks.

Comment: A [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/185834/21564).

Comment: Your example with a triple product on $H^{n/3}$ is an instance of essentially mod $2$ phenomenon - it just says the "product" on $H^a\times H^a\times H^a$ is symmetric if all $a$ are even and antisymmetric otherwise.

Comment: "But do these trilinear forms give nontrivial invariants of M?" Yes. The first example is the discriminant of a symmetric cubic form, which is an integer. So there is an integer topological invariant $M \mapsto \Delta(M)$ which only makes sense for manifolds of dimension 6k. In dimension 6, when the manifold admits a complex structure there are some connections of the discriminant to its complex geometry, and a nice formula for the discriminant of a $\mathbb{CP}^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^2$, and more. See the paper mentioned above.

Comment: "dimension mod 3, or 6, or 12." -- why not "dimension mod 3, or 9, or 27." ?

Comment: Indeed, go ahead and pick your own favorite integers.  I gave some very simple examples of how the existence of certain invariants depends on the dimension mod 3 or 6.

Comment: My PhD student, Yang Hu, is about to post a paper about topological complex vector bundles over complex projective spaces (using Weiss calculus), and the answer depends on the dimension of the projective space modulo 24.

Answer (score 10):

I [learned](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week197.html) recently that the 'topological modular form' cohomology theory  TMF has $576$-fold periodicity.  Not quite period $3$, but similar, since $576=3^2 \times 2^6$.

Comment: Do I understand right that one can think of this as a very fancy version of the fact that elliptic curves are kind of annoying in characteristics 2 and 3?

Comment: Safe to say that both phenomena spring from the same source.

Comment: @NoahSnyder Is "kind of annoying" a phrase that's synonymous with "fascinating and subtle?"  :)

Comment: The world would be a really boring place without the primes $2$ and $3$...

Comment: For those who want to learn what $\pi_*(TMF)$ is without learning what $TMF$ is, I can recommend my survey chapter http://www.christopherleedouglas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/TMF-preliminary.pdf, starting at page 211. More precisely: pages 211-214.

Comment: The linked page contains the sentence "$\mathit{tmf}_n$ is the space of supersymmetric 2d conformal field theories of central charge -n". This is not the most up-to-date version of the conjecture. The more up-to-date version reads: "$\mathit{TMF}_n$ is the space of $\mathcal N$=(0,1) supersymmetric 2d quantum field theories of gravitational anomaly -n". The significant changes are tmf --> TMF, and CFT --> QFT.

Comment: Does the $24^2$-periodicity of TMF imply that the topology of $n$-manifolds is similar in some way to the topology to the topology of $(n+24^2)$-manifolds?   If so, some details would be great.

Comment: @JohnBaez I don't see a direct statement of the form 'w(X) only depends on $d(X) \mod 576$.  So this might not be an answer.  $TMF(X)$ is a $d$-dimensional family of QFTs with target space of dimension $n$, so there's still a step needed to link $d$ and $n$.  I was hoping to spot something in the Witten genus, but no luck yet.